# Not able raising an event in moq, nothing happens when i subscribe

Tags: moq

I am writing some unit tests and I am using the Moq framework to mock some of my classes.  The code I am writing is very simple:

```
Mock<IApp> _iAppMock;
bool _changed;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _iAppMock = new Mock<IApp>();
    _iAppMock.Setup(i => i.Back()).Raises(i => i.Changed += OnEventHandler);
    _changed = false;
}

private void OnEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Heeellllo");
    _changed = true;
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    _iAppMock.Object.Back();
    Assert.IsTrue(_changed);
}
```

When I run the test, the `OnEventHandler` method is never executed. How can I fire an event and subscribe to it using the Moq framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the `Raises` method is just there to tell the mock which event to raise and with which event arguments; it doesn't actually hook the event up to your handler.  Use this instead:

```cs
// Set up the mock to raise the "Changed" event when Back() is called
_iAppMock.Setup(i => i.Back()).Raises(i => i.Changed += null, EventArgs.Empty);

// Attach the event handler here as normal.
_iAppMock.Object.Changed += OnEventHandler;
```

Refer to the [Events section of the Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events) for more examples.

Comment: Upvoted, but you need to give the parameter(s) in `Raises` (unless the signature of the delegate takes zero parameters which is not the case here). _Addition:_ For example `.Raises(i => i.Changed += null, yourSender, yourEventArgs);`. For the particular pattern with an `object sender` and an `EventArgs e`, the first parameter "sender" can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing the Handler to `Raise` method.
Try to pass the EventArgs as `EventArgs.Empty` like

```
 _iAppMock.Setup(i => i.Back()).Raises(i => i.Changed += OnEventHandler, EventArgs.Empty);
```